# illegal atomic form

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un simple programa para familiarizarme con `c#`, en la cual tenés que adivinar un número, `vscode` no me marca ningún error, pero a la hora de compilar, me dice:

> **Syntax error: illegal atomic form: () inside expression `(public ...)'**

```
    Expansion history:

    <syntax>          (##core#begin (public class Game (public int min = 0 public int get_difficulty () (int max = 0 Conso...
    <syntax>          (public class Game (public int min = 0 public int get_difficulty () (int max = 0 Console.WriteLine (...
    <syntax>          (public int min = 0 public int get_difficulty () (int max = 0 Console.WriteLine ("Choose the difficu...       <--
```

> **Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 17920:**
>   **'/usr/bin/chicken' 'guess_the_number.cs' -output-file**
>   **'guess_the_number.c'**

Si no entiendo mal es un error de sintaxis, pero conozco la sintaxis de `c#`, y el compilador no me dice muy bien cuál sería el error.
Mi código: https://paste.mod.gg/nevatigaca.cs

Comment: En c# las clases y funciones empiezan y terminan con {}, y lineas terminan con ;  No entiendo como escribiió su código, es muy dificil leer.

Comment: cuando defines el `public int main () {` donde haces el `return`? porque este retorna un int peor no veo donde

Comment: Todas mis lineas terminan con ; y tanto el namespace como la clase cierran y abren, tambien probe poner el return 0 pero no cambia nada, es irrelevante para el main si tiene return o no